Create Azure Postgres Database with private endpoint on delegated private subnet using terraform
I am encountering challenges when attempting to create a PostgreSQL flexible server with a private endpoint in Azure using Terraform. Additionally, I have attached a Network Security Group (NSG) to the delegated private subnet associated with the PostgreSQL flexible server. Using location as
Central India and B_Standard_B1ms for db_sku.
Tried with different SKUs and locations as well but the same error.
Below, I have included the Terraform script and the error message I am receiving.
"azurerm_private_dns_zone" "postgres_dns_zone" {
      name                = "${var.project_name}${var.environment}.postgres.database.azure.com"
      resource_group_name = var.resource_group
      tags                = var.tags
    }
    

    resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "db" {
      name                          = "${var.project_name}${var.environment}postgres"
      resource_group_name           = var.resource_group
      location                      = var.location
      administrator_login           = var.db_admin
      administrator_password        = random_password.postgres_password.result
      sku_name                      = var.db_sku
      zone                          = var.zone
      version                       = var.db_version
      delegated_subnet_id           = var.subnet_id
      private_dns_zone_id           = azurerm_private_dns_zone.postgres_dns_zone.id
      storage_mb                    = var.db_storage
      backup_retention_days         = 7
      geo_redundant_backup_enabled  = false
      public_network_access_enabled = false
      dynamic "high_availability" {
        for_each = var.enable_ha ? [1] : []
        content {
          mode                     = "ZoneRedundant"
          standby_availability_zone = var.ha_zone
        }
      }
    
      depends_on                    = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.postgres_dns_zone]
      tags                          = var.tags
    }
    resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_configuration" "postgis" {
      name      = "azure.extensions"
      server_id = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.db.id
      value = "POSTGIS"
    }
    
    # Link private DNS zone with the VNet for PostgreSQL
    resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "pg_dns_vnet_link" {
      name                  = "${azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.db.name}-vnetlink.com"
      resource_group_name   = var.resource_group
      private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.postgres_dns_zone.name
      virtual_network_id    = var.vnet_id
      tags                  = var.tags
      depends_on = [ azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.db ]
    }
    
    
    # Private endpoint for PostgreSQL
    resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "postgres_private_endpoint" {
      name                = "${azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.db.name}-private-endpoint"
      resource_group_name = var.resource_group
      location            = var.location
      subnet_id           = var.subnet_id
      tags                = var.tags
    
      private_service_connection {
        name                           = "${azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.db.name}-Connection"
        is_manual_connection           = false
        private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.db.id
        subresource_names              = ["postgresqlServer"]
      }
    
      private_dns_zone_group {
        name = "${azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.db.name}-private-dns-zone-group"
        private_dns_zone_ids = [
          azurerm_private_dns_zone.postgres_dns_zone.id
        ]  
      }
      depends_on = [ azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.db,  azurerm_private_dns_zone.postgres_dns_zone ]
    
    }

The Vnet code is as below:
############
## VNET ##
############
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "controltower_vnet" {
  name                = "${var.project_name}-${var.environment}-vnet"
  address_space       = var.cidr_range
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  tags                = var.tags
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [tags]
  }
}

############
## SUBNET ##
############
resource "azurerm_subnet" "controltower_public" {
  count                = length(var.public_subnet_cidrs)
  name                 = "${var.project_name}-${var.environment}-public-subnet-${count.index + 1}"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.controltower_vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = [var.public_subnet_cidrs[count.index]]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "controltower_private" {
  count                = length(var.private_subnet_cidrs)
  name                 = "${var.project_name}-${var.environment}-private-subnet-${count.index + 1}"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.controltower_vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = [var.private_subnet_cidrs[count.index]]
  default_outbound_access_enabled = false
  dynamic "delegation" {
    for_each = count.index == 0 ? [1] : []
    content {
      name = "postgresql-delegation"
      
      service_delegation {
        name = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers"
        actions = [
          #"Microsoft.Network/networkinterfaces/*",
          #"Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/join/action",
          #"Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/read",
          #"Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/read",
          "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action",
          #"Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
          #"Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action",
          #"Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/unprepareNetworkPolicies/action"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  service_endpoints = count.index == 0 ? ["Microsoft.Sql" , "Microsoft.Storage"] : []

  private_endpoint_network_policies = "Enabled"
}

#########
## NAT ##
#########
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "controltower_nat_ip" {
  name                = "${var.project_name}-${var.environment}-nat-ip"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = var.publicip_sku
  tags                = var.tags
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [tags]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_nat_gateway" "controltower_nat" {
  name                = "${var.project_name}-${var.environment}-ngw"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  location            = var.location
  sku_name            = var.nat_sku
  tags                = var.tags
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [tags]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_nat_gateway_public_ip_association" "controltower_nat_association" {
  nat_gateway_id       = azurerm_nat_gateway.controltower_nat.id
  public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.controltower_nat_ip.id
}

# Associate NAT Gateway with private subnets
resource "azurerm_subnet_nat_gateway_association" "controltower_private_nat_association" {
  count          = length(var.private_subnet_cidrs)
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.controltower_private[count.index].id
  nat_gateway_id = azurerm_nat_gateway.controltower_nat.id
}

#############
## ROUTING ##
#############

# Route table for private subnets
resource "azurerm_route_table" "controltower_private_rt" {
  name                = "${var.project_name}-private-rt"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  tags                = var.tags
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [tags]
  }
}

# Route table for public subnets
resource "azurerm_route_table" "controltower_public_rt" {
  name                = "${var.project_name}-public-rt"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  tags                = var.tags
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [tags]
  }
}

# **Single Route for Private Subnets**: This will apply to all private subnets via the NAT gateway
resource "azurerm_route" "controltower_private_route" {
  name                = "route-private"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  route_table_name    = azurerm_route_table.controltower_private_rt.name
  address_prefix      = "0.0.0.0/0" # Route all outbound traffic
  next_hop_type       = "Internet"  # Azure handles NAT gateway routing automatically
}

# Route for public subnets (directly to Internet)
resource "azurerm_route" "controltower_public_route" {
  count               = length(var.public_subnet_cidrs)
  name                = "route-public-${count.index + 1}"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  route_table_name    = azurerm_route_table.controltower_public_rt.name
  address_prefix      = "0.0.0.0/0" # Route all outbound traffic to the Internet
  next_hop_type       = "Internet"
}

##################
## ASSOCIATIONS ##
##################

# Associate private subnets with private route table
resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "controltower_private_association" {
  count          = length(var.private_subnet_cidrs)
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.controltower_private[count.index].id
  route_table_id = azurerm_route_table.controltower_private_rt.id
}

# Associate public subnets with public route table
resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "controltower_public_association" {
  count          = length(var.public_subnet_cidrs)
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.controltower_public[count.index].id
  route_table_id = azurerm_route_table.controltower_public_rt.id
}

#########
## NSG ##
#########
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "controltower_nsg" {
  name                = "${var.project_name}-nsg"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  tags                = var.tags
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [tags]
  }
}

locals {
  port_rules = {
    for port in var.ports : port => {
      priority = 100 + index(var.ports, port)
      name     = "allow-${port}"
    }
  }
}

# Create security rules for each port
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "allow_inbound" {
  for_each = local.port_rules

  name                        = each.value.name
  priority                    = each.value.priority
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_address_prefixes     = var.inbound_ips
  source_port_range           = "*"
  destination_address_prefix  = "*"
  destination_port_ranges     = [each.key]
  network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.controltower_nsg.name
  resource_group_name         = var.resource_group
}

######################
## NSG ASSOCIATIONS ##
######################

# Associate NSG with public subnets
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "controltower_public_nsg_association" {
  count                     = length(var.public_subnet_cidrs)
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.controltower_public[count.index].id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.controltower_nsg.id
}

# Associate NSG with private subnets
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "controltower_private_nsg_association" {
  count                     = length(var.private_subnet_cidrs)
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.controltower_private[count.index].id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.controltower_nsg.id
}

But getting the below error:
╷
│ Error: creating Private Endpoint (Subscription: "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
│ Resource Group Name: "test-dev-rg"
│ Private Endpoint Name: "testdevdb-private-endpoint"): performing CreateOrUpdate: unexpected status 400 (400 Bad Request) with error: PrivateEndpointFeatureNotSupportedOnServer: Call to Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers failed. Error message: The given server testdevdb does not support private endpoint feature. Please create a new server that is private endpoint capable. Refer to https://aka.ms/pgflex-pepreview for more details.
│
│   with module.DB.azurerm_private_endpoint.postgres_private_endpoint,
│   on ..\modules\database\db.tf line 68, in resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "postgres_private_endpoint":
│   68: resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "postgres_private_endpoint" {
│


did you tried changing the sku and location because few regions and sku doesn't support the private end point for PostgreSQL server @Jonty

It would be helpful for answerers to understand what about the message “The given server controltowerdevpostgres does not support private endpoint feature. Please create a new server that is private endpoint capable” is unclear to you; you’ll get more targeted answers this way. Do you mind editing your question to elaborate on this point?


Create Azure Postgres Server with private endpoint using terraform

While creating a Postgres Server with private endpoint we need to make sure that the SKU and region we select show support the feature requirement.
Before running the deployment, we can make sure the configuration of PostgreSQL should be in confirmed by the commands given below.
 az postgres flexible-server list-skus --location <your location> --output table

I tried a demo configuration with the configuration that suitable to achieve this requirement as mentioned below.
Configuration:
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = "vinay-pg-rg"
  location = "westeurope"  
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = "vksb-pg-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.88.0.0/16"]  
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "main" {
  name                 = "vksb-pg-main-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.88.2.0/24"]

  private_endpoint_network_policies = "Enabled"

  service_endpoints = ["Microsoft.Sql"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "main" {
  name                = "vksb-pg-main-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name

  security_rule {
    name                       = "PostgreSQL"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "5432"
    source_address_prefix      = "0.0.0.0/0"  
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }

  security_rule {
    name                       = "HTTPS"
    priority                   = 110
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "443"
    source_address_prefix      = "0.0.0.0/0"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "main" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.main.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.main.id
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "postgres_dns_zone" {
  name                = "privatelink.postgres.database.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "main" {
  name                          = "vksb-postgresql"
  location                      = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  version                       = "16"                    
  sku_name                      = "B_Standard_B2s"        
  administrator_login           = "sqladmin"                
  administrator_password        = "yourpassword"         
  storage_mb                    = 32768                    
  storage_tier                  = "P4"                  
  public_network_access_enabled = false
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "main" {
  name                  = "vksb-postgresql-main-vnet-link"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.postgres_dns_zone.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.main.id

  depends_on = [azurerm_subnet.main, azurerm_virtual_network.main]
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "main" {
  name                = "vksb-postgresql-main"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.main.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "vksb-postgresql-psc"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main.id
    subresource_names              = ["postgresqlServer"]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main.name
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.postgres_dns_zone.id]
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main, azurerm_subnet.main]
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_database" "db" {
  name      = "vksb-pg-main-db"
  server_id = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main.id
  charset   = "UTF8" 
  collation = "en_US.utf8"  

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.main]
}

Deployment:



Refer:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/explore/global-infrastructure/products-by-region/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-networking-private
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-networking-private-link

I'm using Central India and B_Standard_B1ms for db_sku which listed in the az command but still getting the same error, I've added the network part as well

which means that sku or region not supporting the private endpoint change to the valid sku and region please change these two and try again

Tried by changing the sku to general purpose still same but as per the documentation postgres flexible server does support private endpoint for all the sku in all region source:-  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/availability

that what i try to convey in the comment please change the region and sku that support for private end point as i did in the configuration inshared for demo purpose .. that region andn sku support the private end point requirement

Yes, I tried the same configuration but still same and also getting the same error from console. Is there any possibility that it is due to the vnet configuration?? Using the private subnet, subnet[0] from the vnet.tf file

any way for this issue? giving same error if try to create with different location and sku

refer this once https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1442769/i-was-trying-to-deploy-postgresql-with-private-end and the follow up doc and check whether your network connectivity matches as per this requirement

yes it's same only , rather I've added route tables as well for both private and public subnet
